# 'Radio Location' skill vs. white 'Located' arrow

Tags: world-of-warships

[image]

I triple-checked, and NONE of my captains have the 4-pt [Radio Location](https://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Ship:Commander#List_of_Versatility_Skills) Captain Skill. But I still see this white Located arrow — see the yellow arrow in the screenshot overhead.

1. What's the purpose of the Radio Location skill? Isn't the 'Radio Location' skill redundant, when the game provides this white 'Located' arrow by default and for free?
2. Can you pls distinguish the Radio Location skill vs. this white 'Located' arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white arrow does not indicate that you are using the radio location skill. It indicates that there is a player on the enemy team using the skill, and they have located **you**. The icon is always in the exact same location on your screen so it won't indicate where the enemy is.

This can indicate that you are in trouble, if you're trying to sneak around the flanks of the enemy they now know where you are.

When your captain has the radio location skill you will see a white arch on screen indicating where the closest enemy ship is.

[image: radio location skill in action]